# JQuery Easing Button Gets Affected For All Wordpress Posts Instead Of One Of A Time

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-easing

I've added a JQuery button on the right side of each wordpress post's title, the thing is, when I click on one of the buttons to open the box, all the rest of the post's boxes opens too, instead of opening one of a time. Here's the URL: http://experiencias.freeserver.me/

**This code is placed in "index.php"** where is the Post's attributes

```
<a href="#" class="square-toggle">&nbsp;</a>
```

I've added this code but this only works for single posts, it don't affect on the home page

```
<?php if(is_single ()) { ?>
    <a href="#" class="square-toggle">&nbsp;</a>
<?php } ?>
```

The Js Code:

```
    $('.square').hide();
    $('a.square-toggle').click(function() {
      $('.square').slideToggle('fast');
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: Can you post your JS code?

Comment: I've added it to the question @Stefan-Dunn

Comment: The problem is you are applying the SlideToggle to ALL objects with class "square".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't designed to work for multiple elements on the same page and hence your troubles.
Try this.

Change this in the custom.js for the theme,

From:

```
//Hidden box on homepage
$('.square').hide();
$('a.square-toggle').click(function() {
$('.square').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

To:

```
//Hidden box on homepage
$('.square').hide();
$('a.square-toggle').click(function() {
//First make sure all squares are hidden again incase one is already open
$('.square').hide();
//now get the parent of the square-toggle and within that get .box>.square and slide it
$('.box .square', $(this).parent()).slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/VRpL5/

Comment: Awesome! It worked. But how can I make the square box close too when I click again?

Comment: Change `$('.square').hide();` to `$('.square').slideUp('fast');`
http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :\ I don't have a really good Js knowledge but I tried add this before the `});` parameters: `$('.square').hide();` and it does the work, but only if you click it twice.

Comment: Try this, it won't hide any previously selected ones but will hide a particular one if clicked again http://jsfiddle.net/VRpL5/1/

Comment: Awesome! that's the final result that I wanted. Well it won't hide any previous one but my major priority was closing it again. Guess we can't have it all :P
Thanks a lot for your help, you're awesome ;)

Comment: Do you know what awesome is?! Man, you're plenty above that! Thank you so much :D

Comment: Hey @Rob-Schmuecker , I'm having a problem here  

When I click on the menu tab of this new plugin that I installed (which is the first button on the right side localized on the menu top bar with hover animation), it gives an animation for all the posts to switch to posts by categorie or all posts, and when I access any of these tabs from this plugin's menu, the box I created based on this script you gave me, stops working and the button work's only as a link.

Here's the URL: [Website URL](http://experiencias.freeserver.me/)

Comment: ok - that is because the plugin seems to be changing the HTML (the posts depending on category etc) after the initial listener has been run.  Hence the buttons of the new/filtered "posts" are new in the dom and won't be acted upon by your code.  What you need is "delegated events" http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events, have a look at this example, it should either work with your plugin or get you in the right direction http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/VRpL5/4/